# Ebay API GetCategorySpecifics Error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, ebay-api

After checking many different options, I think it's time to ask questions to the experts :).

I'm trying to make an eBay API Service call using the GetCategorySpecifics call, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

Here's my code

```
//Create the XML File
public string CreateEbayXMLFile()
 { 
        string _ebayFeatureNS = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents";
        string resultXml = "";
        XDocument doc = new XDocument
        (
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", ""),
            new XElement(_ebayFeatureNS + "GetCategorySpecifics",
            new XElement(_ebayFeatureNS + "CategorySpecific", true),
            new XElement(_ebayFeatureNS + "CategoryID", "CategoryID"),
            new XElement(_ebayFeatureNS + "FeatureID", "ItemSpecificsEnabled"),
            new XElement(_ebayFeatureNS + "ViewAllNodes", true),
            new XElement(_ebayFeatureNS + "DetailLevel", "ReturnAll"),
            new XElement(_ebayFeatureNS + "CategorySpecificsFileInfo", "true"),
            new XElement(_ebayFeatureNS + "ExcludeRelationships", "false"),
            new XElement(_ebayFeatureNS + "IncludeConfidence", "true"),
            new XElement(_ebayFeatureNS + "MaxNames"),
            new XElement(_ebayFeatureNS + "OutputSelector", "UnitPriceInfo")
            )
       );
    resultXml = doc.ToString();
    return resultXml;
 }

  //Make the Service Call
   public XmlDocument MakeTheServiceCall()
    {
       string localEbayXml = CreateEbayXMLFile();
       string _ebaySvcUrl = http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1;

      //Authentication and service call
       byte[] Xml_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(localEbayReqXml);
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(_ebaySvcUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
                req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME", myAppId);
                req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "GetCategorySpecifics");
                req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION", "1.0.0");
                req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID", "EBAY-US");
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentLength = Xml_bytes.Length;
                req.ContentType = "text/xml";

                using (var requestStream = req.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(Xml_bytes, 0, Xml_bytes.Length);
                }

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
                {
                    {
                        xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
                    }
                }

    }
```

I received the error message on the HttpWebResponse declaration.  It never reaches xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the url to https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll and the problem is resolved.  So instead of:

```
   string _ebaySvcUrl = http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1;
```

It's

```
   string _ebaySvcUrl = http://svcs.ebay.com/MerchandisingService
```

The former one would work with services `findCompletedItems`, `findItemsByKeywords` and so on.

For a list of some other url and when to use them, see the link below:

https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=429